# Help in mysql query

Tags: mysql, php, mysql-5.0

I have a column in database with name `paid_amount` that have multiple values with a separator like:

```
1,2,4,10
```

I need the sum of these values: sum = 17

```
select sum(paid_amount) from invoices where ins_no = 2
```

Comment: What is your MySQL version? Does the maximum of the amount of "values per field" exists?

Comment: mysql 5.0 no limit for values

Comment: *no limit for values* It is theory. But in practice the limit must exist (and it can be calculated from the field data type). How much is it? *mysql 5.0* I recommend to create stored procedure (to obtain the whole `ins_no` - `sum` recordset) or user-defined function (to obtain the `sum` for specified `ins_no` value).

Comment: Plan A:  Do it in your application code, where it will be easier.  Plan B:  Redesign the schema; commalists are "bad".

Answer (score 0):

I'm a SQL Server DBA and i faced this question as a challenge

First I found this function to split the values

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14950466/how-to-split-the-name-string-in-mysql**

With this function a create this procedure below

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile(IN ID VARCHAR(5))
BEGIN
    select @total := length(replace(paid_amount,',','')) as coluna from invoices where ins_no = ID;

    SET @c := 0;
    SET @t := 0;

  while @c < @total  DO

        select @t := @t +  SPLIT_STR(paid_amount, ',', @c )  as coluna from invoices where ins_no = ID;

        SET @c :=  @c + 1;
    end while;
    select @t;
END
```

just run this comand

```
call dowhile(2);
```

I think this will be enough